# Count number of characters in a string whose ASCII code is multiple of number 3 without using loop or recursion

Tags: php, foreach

I have the following PHP code which uses foreach and gives the correct count. This is what I tried with loop.

```php
$str = 'hello world';
$cnt = 0;

$arr = str_split($str);
foreach($arr as $val){
  if( ord($val)%3 == 0 ){
   $cnt++;
  }
}
echo 'total count- '.$cnt; //count is 6 here which is correct
```

Is there a way of doing the same thing in `PHP` without the use of loops or recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHPs inbuilt array functions to do this, but internally they loop over the values themselves so is that valid? One way would be to use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) on the results of [`str_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and then getting the count of the number of values in the resultant array:

```
$str = 'hello world';
$cnt = count(array_filter(str_split($str), function ($v) { return ord($v) % 3 == 0; }));
echo $cnt;
```

Output

```
6
```

You can also do something similar with [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) (this is most similar to your existing code):

```
$cnt = array_reduce(str_split($str), function ($c, $v) { return $c + (ord($v) % 3 == 0 ? 1 : 0); }, 0);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/rCKYp)